# How to use gluPerspective only once?

Tags: c++, opengl, perspective, glu

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//set viewpoint
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(VIEW_ANGLE,Screen_Ratio,NEAR_CLIP,FAR_CLIP);
gluLookAt(0,5,5, 0,0,0, 0,1,0);

//transform model 1
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(Theta, 0,1,0);

//draw model 1
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
glEnd();
```

The code above works fine, but is there any way to remove the call to gluPerspective?

What I mean is, I would like to call it only once in initialization, instead of repeatedly during each rendering.

Comment: because without calling gluPerspective there in the code, rendering comes to unexpected result.

Comment: Why are you so keen to avoid this though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call gluPerspective there, because it belongs there. OpenGL is not a scene graph where you initialize things. It's a state driven drawing API. The projection matrix is a state and every serious graphics application changes this state multiple times throughout a single frame rendering.

OpenGL does not know geometrical objects, positions and cameras. It just pushes points, lines and triangles through a processing pipeline, and draws the result to the screen. After something has been drawn, OpenGL has no recollection of it, whatsoever.

> I mean calling it only once in initialization.

OpenGL is not initialized (except creation of the rendering context, but actually this is part of the operating system's graphics stack, not OpenGL). Sure, you upload textures and buffer object data to it, but that can happen anytime.

Answer (score 4):

Do **not** use `gluLookAt` on the projection matrix, as it defines the camera/view and therefore belongs to the modelview matrix, usually as the left-most transformation (the first after `glLoadIdentity`), where it makes up the view part of the word modelview. Although it also works your way, it's conceptually wrong. This would also solve your issue, as then you just don't have to touch the projection matrix every frame.

But actually datenwolf's approach is more conceptually clean regarding OpenGL's state machine architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call [`glLoadIdentity()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) (which resets the current matrix to be the identity matrix, i.e. undoes what `gluPerspective()` has done) every frame and instead carefully [push/pop](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) the transform matrices you can get away with calling it only in initialization quite happily. Usually it's far easier just to call load identity each time your start drawing and then reset it. e.g.:

```
// Initalisation
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(...);
```

Then later on:

```
// Drawing each frame
glClear(...);

glPushMatrix();
gluLookAt(...);

//draw stuff

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: does using glPushMatrix & glPopMatrix increase performance a lot? compare to moving every object to root (in the case of calling to glLoadIdentity)

Comment: I wouldn't obsess about the performance of an operation like that, which happens once per frame. It just isn't worth it. Worry about the big things like geometry and shaders and textures and all that. Compared to those measuring the cost of `glLoadIdentity()` + `gluPerspective()` vs `glPushMatrix()` + `glPopMatrix()` is virtually impossible.